# Is position(X,Y) in figure

Tags: collision-detection

I have a small problem and i hope you can explain it to me.

I have something like that: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq3Ne.png). Is there a simple way to determine if X5, Y8 is a position that is **inside** that figure? I have no clue how i should do that sorry.

Comment: Exemplify better. Are you working with canvas?

Comment: @AksJacoves I have 3D game with a coordinate system. And i want to know if the player  is inside a specific area (i dont care for height) (The area is created dynamically)  Thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: I don't know how you worked on your coordinate system, so I can only make suggestions. One that comes to mind is to create invisible segments that cross the character and accompany it, for example: Considering that it is a pixel, we can consider it as the center of a circle, so we could trace some segments on that circle that pass through the center of it (0º, 45º, 180º for example)

Comment: And then do a check if all the segments are tangent to the segments of the figure, if the answer is no then it is not inside

Comment: I thought of like you said, make an invisible line in front of the player that goes a little bit deeper and then to check if that line interacts with an line from the figure. But if i am honest i dont know how the math works for that. (The figure has like ...5-6 points each and is set dynamically by the player (on the ground) and is just lines connecting to each other)

Comment: A simpler device that you could do is to set an opacity very close to 1 so that it is unnoticeable, and then if the player enters that object, his opacity should also be changed, and based on the player's opacity you would check if he entered or not in the figure

Comment: Like i said above its just connected points, there is technically no object? or do i understand something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

This solved it for me. I hope it helps somebody else.